# Compilation unit normalizewhitespace crash with parsed "For"/"Next" Statements

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am facing an issue where when i create a dummy namespace, class and sub, and add parsed statements for a For/Next loop, it crashes on the NormalizeWhitespace method of my compilation unit.

```
IndexOutOfRangeException
Index was outside the bounds of the array.
at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1.Builder.get_Item(Int32 index)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.SyntaxNormalizer.GetIdentation(Int32 count)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.SyntaxNormalizer.RewriteTrivia(SyntaxTriviaList triviaList, Int32 depth, Boolean isTrailing, Boolean mustBeIndented, Boolean mustHaveSeparator, Int32 lineBreaksAfter, Int32 lineBreaksBefore)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.SyntaxNormalizer.VisitToken(SyntaxToken token)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.VisualBasicSyntaxRewriter.VisitEndBlockStatement(EndBlockStatementSyntax node)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.SyntaxNormalizer.VisitEndBlockStatement(EndBlockStatementSyntax node)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.EndBlockStatementSyntax.Accept[TResult](VisualBasicSyntaxVisitor`1 visitor)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.VisualBasicSyntaxRewriter.Visit(SyntaxNode node)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.VisualBasicSyntaxRewriter.VisitNamespaceBlock(NamespaceBlockSyntax node)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.SyntaxNormalizer.VisitNamespaceBlock(NamespaceBlockSyntax node)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.NamespaceBlockSyntax.Accept[TResult](VisualBasicSyntaxVisitor`1 visitor)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.VisualBasicSyntaxRewriter.Visit(SyntaxNode node)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.VisualBasicSyntaxRewriter.VisitListElement[TNode](TNode node)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.VisualBasicSyntaxRewriter.VisitList[TNode](SyntaxList`1 list)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.VisualBasicSyntaxRewriter.VisitCompilationUnit(CompilationUnitSyntax node)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.SyntaxNormalizer.VisitCompilationUnit(CompilationUnitSyntax node)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.CompilationUnitSyntax.Accept[TResult](VisualBasicSyntaxVisitor`1 visitor)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.VisualBasicSyntaxRewriter.Visit(SyntaxNode node)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.SyntaxNormalizer.Normalize[TNode](TNode node, String indentWhitespace, String eolWhitespace, Boolean useElasticTrivia, Boolean useDefaultCasing)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.SyntaxExtensions.NormalizeWhitespace[TNode](TNode node, Boolean useDefaultCasing, String indentation, Boolean elasticTrivia)
at UserQuery.Main()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Here's the code to reproduce:

```
public void Main()
{
   var compilationUnit = SyntaxFactory.CompilationUnit();
   compilationUnit = compilationUnit.AddMembers(this.CreateNamespaceDeclaration());
   compilationUnit = compilationUnit.NormalizeWhitespace(true, "\r\n", false);
   compilationUnit.ToFullString().Dump();
}

public string[] StatementList = { "For i As Integer = 0 To 10", "Dim v = 0", "Next" };

// Define other methods and classes here

private NamespaceBlockSyntax CreateNamespaceDeclaration()
{
    return SyntaxFactory.NamespaceBlock(
        SyntaxFactory.NamespaceStatement(
        SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("Test")))
        .WithMembers(
            SyntaxFactory.SingletonList<StatementSyntax>(
                SyntaxFactory.ClassBlock(
                SyntaxFactory.ClassStatement("VBCrash")
                .WithModifiers(
                    SyntaxFactory.TokenList(
                        SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword))))
        .WithImplements(SyntaxFactory.List<ImplementsStatementSyntax>())
        .WithMembers(SyntaxFactory.List<StatementSyntax>(
                SyntaxFactory.List<StatementSyntax>()
                .Add(SyntaxFactory.SubBlock(
                SyntaxFactory.SubStatement("Main"))
            .AddStatements(this.AddStatements()))))));
}


private StatementSyntax[] AddStatements()
{
    var result = default(SyntaxList<StatementSyntax>);

    foreach (var statement in StatementList)
    {
        result = result.Add(SyntaxFactory.ParseExecutableStatement(statement));
    }

    return result.ToArray();
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Whenever i comment the foreach loop for the statements, it works.

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: It generates VB Cal-cium....

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax tree isn't of a valid shape. Parsing block statements has structure; you can't parse a line-at-a-time like that and group them together and expect to get a meaningful tree out of it. (I think you were doing this same thing in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154062/unable-to-parse-code-snippet-in-roslyn) which was going to cause problems there too.) You should be parsing all of those statements in one go, rather than one-at-a-time. Again, use the scripting parsing mode if you want top-level statements.

Still, the formatter shouldn't be crashing like this. File a bug on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn).